# ReportViewer doesn't print Color on other machines

Tags: .net, colors, printing, reportviewer

I have a very simple C# WinForms project with a ReportViewer control docked in the center.  I've created a local report (rdlc) file that contains an embedded color picture.  If I compile and run this on my local machine, I can view the color image and print to my color printer and everything works fine.

If I move the application to a different machine with the same version of the reportviewer redistributable installed, I get different results.  I still see the color image in the ReportViewer control, but when I try to print to the same color printer, my report comes out in black and white.  I can export this to a PDF report and the color stays, so printer from Report>PDF>Printer works for color, just not straight to the printer.

Does anyone have any similar experiences?

Edit* Update -- Some elements on the report print in color, like blue font, but everything else is black and white.

Comment: Check the printer setup, is it set to print in B+W?

Comment: The printer setup is the same for both machines.

Answer (score 1):

What i did is to force print in color.

```
ReportViewer.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
```

Then it will be printed in color.

I am using Epson TM-U220 Ethernet black & red ribbons. I founded that default Printing Preference is 'Monochorme', to check, Run App with report viewer then ReportViewer > Printer > Select a Printer > Preference. The odd is that, in Windows, the Printer Preference set Color as default.

With force color above the default will be Color and it printed Red as designed.